# Is it possible to do mini (soft) reload when some route is visited?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, vue.js, vue-router, reload

So I have if else statement that looks at the end of URL to determine which answers to provide. (It's a simple quiz widget). Right now it works as expected but when I proceed from question to next question, the answer is the same as the last question until I move the slider to choose an answer. I want to be able that when I visit next question answers would update automatically. Either by doing some kind of soft reload or I actually don't know that's why I'm asking here.

TY for all help.

Comment: Could you share more details ?

Comment: Are you using vue-router?

Comment: @DelenaMalan yes i am

Comment: @dimas just say what i am glad to share anything for help

Comment: What does your route configuration in vue-router for the routes you're mentioning look like? It's not really clear what your setup is so you might need to add some code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In General you need to build you application logic based on your URL.

In your router:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/quiz/:id', component: Quiz }
  ]
})
```

In your Quiz component you need to define computed property:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        questions: ['First q', 'Second q'],
        answers: [....]
    }
},
computed: {
    currentQuestion() {
        const qID = parseInt(this.$route.params.id, 10);
        if (qID >= 0) {
            return this.questions[qId];
        }
        return '';
    },
    currentAnswers() {
        const qID = parseInt(this.$route.params.id, 10);
        if (qID >= 0) {
            return this.answers[qId];
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

And moving to a new question may be like
`router.push({ name: 'quiz', params: { id: '123' } })`